# Why a child process fails to write to a shared memory?

Tags: c

I have a simple program that writes to a shared memory and reads from a shared memory,  but while reading I am getting segmentation fault.

When I am debugging, the child process is not writing information to the shared memory, and after that, the parent process is trying to read from the shared memory which has no data and is throwing segmentation fault at 1st printf,  in parent `printf("%d\n",ptr->nread);`

Why the child process is not able to write data to the shared memory? (it is failing at `ptr->nread=20;` line)

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#define  SIZE 5*1024
struct databuf{
    int nread;
    char *buf;
    int xyz;
};
    struct databuf* ptr;
main()
{
    int shmid,pid;
    shmid = shmget((key_t)1,SIZE,IPC_CREAT|0777);
    pid =  fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
            ptr = (struct databuf *)shmat(shmid,(char*)0,0);
            ptr->nread=20;
            ptr->buf=ptr+sizeof(ptr->nread);
            strcpy(ptr->buf, "abc");
            ptr->xyz=20;
    }
    else
    {
        wait(0);
        ptr = (struct databuf *)shmat(shmid,(char*)0,0);
        printf("%d\n",ptr->nread);
        printf("%s\n",ptr->buf);
        printf("%d\n",ptr->xyz);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I am just guessing that `ptr+sizeof(ptr->nread)` should be cast-first. You're unintentionally performing sized pointer arithmetic. Or did you intend to position `ptr->buf` at an address 20x databuf structures from its origin?

Comment: And where is your `#include <unistd.h>` ?

Comment: Hi Craig,I checked, its failing at the statement ptr->nread=20; in the child process why so?

Comment: added unistd.h but no luck

Comment: compiling with this warning:`assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] ptr->buf=ptr+sizeof(ptr->nread);` runs fine on my system.
user@host-PC:MyTestProgs$ ./shmtest 
20
abc
20

Comment: You are not checking the return values from shmget or shmat. Maybe one of them has an error? They both return -1 if there is an error

Answer (score 2):

If `ptr->nread` is failing then you should put a error checking code something like this, before acessing the `ptr`.

```
 ptr = (struct databuf *)shmat(shmid,(char*)0,0);
 if (data == (struct databuf *)(-1)) {
                perror("shmat failed");
                exit(1);
 }
 ptr->nread=20;
```

Ref: http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmat

```
ptr->buf=ptr+sizeof(ptr->nread);
```

could be  written as:

```
 ptr->buf=(char*)ptr+sizeof(struct databuf)+ptr->nread;
```

or

```
 ptr->buf=(char*)ptr+ptr->nread;
```

The string can now be accessed in the parent process.

Brief Explanation:
If you're using shared memory, you have to make sure all the data you want to access in other processes is in the shared memory segment. Leave the data at a specified offset(in your case `ptr+ptr->nread`) in the memory segment. And be careful not to overwrite the existing data in the shared memory. sizeof(ptr->nread) will yield the sizeof(int).

Comment: your absolutely right, system clogged with so may shms.  After removing the shm and creating works, but not its failing at ptr->buf=ptr+sizeof(ptr->nread); is this statement is correct?

Comment: Always reap your children before exiting.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis Could you elaborate on what you are suggesting.

Comment: Initially its failing in child process at ptr->nread=20; then after suggestions i checked   the return value of shmget it as failing and i removed existing shms in the system i tried now it passed the above line  and it only able to read ptr->nread  from shared memory, and no other information and segmentation as well so?
since it still did write/read the statement ptr->buf= ((char*)ptr )+sizeof(ptr->nread);
strcpy(ptr->buf, "abc"); and from parent printf("%s\n",ptr->buf);

Comment: @askmish: A parent must always `wait()` for its children to exit.

Comment: @user3883859: what does `nread` do? Remember that `ptr->buf` and `ptr` are two different kinds of pointer. If you intend to use `ptr->buf` for string operations you should allocate some memory first.

Comment: @askmish That is somewhat the point of the offset address being (incorrectly) calculated. What I think the OP is failing to grasp is `ptr` holds an address in the shared memory block, but the *value* of the address stored in `ptr->buf` is in-fact the very address that `ptr->buf` lays on top of as it also resides in shared memory. Dumping both addresses (`&ptr->buf` and `ptr->buf`) will demonstrate this.

Comment: @WhozCraig `ptr->buf` will be pointing to memory at an offset within the shared memory. But, `ptr->buf` and `ptr` will not be pointing to the same memory address, even though they are in the same memory block, due to that `nread` offset.

Comment: @askmish correct. With `char*` casting, `ptr->buf` will actually hold the address of *itself* within that shared memory block. Ex: `ptr->buf = ((char *)ptr) + sizeof(ptr->nread);` will put the address of `ptr->buf` in the shared segment *in* `ptr->buf` the member var. The  examples in this answer compute different offsets still. `(char*)ptr+ptr->nread;` will drop an address 20 bytes past `ptr` into `ptr->buf` (still in the shared segment), while `ptr+sizeof(ptr->nread);` will exercise pointer math to obtain an address 4 (or 8, depends on x64) databuf *structs* off the `ptr` base address.

Comment: It would have helped *immensely* had the OP specified *exactly* what they were trying to do (i.e. was the intent to reference space immediately passed the structure, or was it something else. Either way your answer is good, thus the uptick.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving to one side all the other issues with the code, I think:

```
shmid = shmget((key_t)1, SIZE, IPC_CREAT|0777) ;
```

is probably a mistake, unless you can (somehow) guarantee that `(key_t)1` is not in use elsewhere.  For parent-child communication, as in this case, the simpler approach is:

```
shmid = shmget((IPC_PRIVATE, SIZE, IPC_CREAT|0777) ;
```

In general, when something apparently inexplicable happens, I find it helps to make sure I have checked for error returns.  In this case: `shmget()` returning `-1` or `shmat()` returning `-1`... and I suspect that both have happened.

---

***Worked solution added by @WhozCraig:***

The following example *works*, and *likely* does what you're trying to accomplish. Pay note to how we calculate the address we store in `ptr->buf` after we home `ptr` to our shared memory base address. We have to leave room for the structure, so we calculate the address to start the first byte *past* the structure back-side.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>

struct databuf
{
    int nread;
    char *buf;
    int xyz;
};

#define SIZE (5*1024)

int main()
{
    // acquire shared memory first (read/write access)
    int shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, SIZE, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    if (shmid == -1)
    {
        perror("Failed to acquire shared emory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // fork child process
    pid_t pid = fork();

    // both parent and child need this. may as well do both before
    //  special casing child vs. parent logic.
    struct databuf *ptr = shmat(shmid,(char*)0,0);
    if (ptr == (void*)(-1))
    {
        perror("Failed to map shared memory to our process");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // child process
    if (pid==0)
    {
        ptr->nread = 20;
        ptr->buf = ((char*)ptr) + sizeof(*ptr);
        strcpy(ptr->buf, "abc");
        ptr->xyz = 30;
    }

    // parent process
    else
    {
        wait(NULL);
        printf("ptr = %p, ptr->buf = %p\n", ptr, ptr->buf);
        printf("%d\n",ptr->nread);
        printf("%s\n",ptr->buf);
        printf("%d\n",ptr->xyz);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Output** (varies by system obviously)

```
ptr = 0x80000, ptr->buf = 0x8000c
20
abc
30
```

it is worth noting that this:

```
ptr->buf = ((char*)ptr) + sizeof(*ptr);
```

could be written as the following, using typed-pointer math:

```
ptr->buf = (char*)(ptr + 1);
```

The location where the cast is applied is important. The first applies it before we do any math, so we need to account for octet count. The second applies it *after* the pointer math, so simply adding one to to the typed pointer `ptr` will move us to the memory immediately past our `ptr` structure base.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer from type T, an addition by one to the pointer will increment it by sizeof(T).

So you have to replace:

```
ptr->buf=ptr+sizeof(ptr->nread);
```

to

```
ptr->buf= ((char*)ptr )+sizeof(ptr->nread);
```

If you don't do that, your pointer will be incremented by sizeof(T)^2.